# MySQL query to replace characters after a specific character

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a MySQL query to alter filenames in a table. The filenames can be...

```
image-name-1_1.jpg
image-name-2_1_1.jpg
image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg
```

I need to replace all the text after the FIRST underscore with `.jpg` which would result in...

```
image-name-1.jpg
image-name-2.jpg
image-name-3.jpg
```

Some values in the table column contain underscores but don't have the `.jpg` extension. For example, `this_can_also_be_a_value` (which needs to be ignored).

Comment: You don't say what you want to happen to `this_can_also_be_a_value`

Comment: Sorry, just updated it.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two regular expressions. One that replaces a matched substring and another that checks to see if the row should be updated at all.

I created a table with your data and added an empty column just to see what it will do.

```sql
CREATE TABLE filenames
  (id          integer,
   filename    varchar(64),
   newfilename varchar(64))

INSERT INTO filenames
  (id, filename)
  VALUES (1, 'image-name-1_1.jpg'),
         (2, 'image-name-2_1_1.jpg'),
         (3, 'image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg'),
         (4, 'this_can_also_be_a_value');
```

You'll have to modify "newfilename" to "filename" in the following SQL once you're confident that it works and doesn't update rows that it shouldn't.

```sql
UPDATE filenames
  SET newfilename = REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '_[^.]*', '')
WHERE filename REGEXP '.*\.jpg$';
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '_[^.]*', '')` matches the text from the first "_" until it finds a ".". It then replaces the match with the empty string `''`.

The `filename REGEXP '.*\.jpg$'` returns true when the string ends with ".jpg". So it will only update those rows.

You can also use:

```sql
UPDATE filenames
  SET newfilename = REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '_.*', '.jpg')
WHERE filename REGEXP '.*\.jpg$';
```

which is more precisely what you specified, since it will replace everything from the first "_" until the end of the string with ".jpg".

Both give me this result:

| id | filename | newfilename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | image-name-1_1.jpg | image-name-1.jpg |
| 2 | image-name-2_1_1.jpg | image-name-2.jpg |
| 3 | image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg | image-name-3.jpg |
| 4 | this_can_also_be_a_value | *null* |

Removing the newfilename column and using `..SET filename..` instead of `..SET newfilename..` gives:

| id | filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | image-name-1.jpg |
| 2 | image-name-2.jpg |
| 3 | image-name-3.jpg |
| 4 | this_can_also_be_a_value |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf5f1f9fe479b7e6471c7b34f0197966)

---

For MySQL 5.7 there's no `REGEXP_REPLACE`, so I think your only option is to first extract the initial part of the string up until the first "_", and then add a trailing ".jpg".

The extraction part can be done with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, like in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630993/12695027) by [glovemobile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191563/glovemobile), where the last parameter determines at which occurrence to cut the string. Since you want to cut the string at the first occurrence, I've set it to 1.

To avoid updating filenames, that does not contain any "_", the `REGEXP` checks both that the string contains a "_" and that the string ends with ".jpg". This will avoid having strings like "image-name-0.jpg" turning into "image-name-0.jpg.jpg":

```
UPDATE filenames
   SET filename = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(filename, '_', 1),'.jpg')
 WHERE filename REGEXP '.*_.*\.jpg$';
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5422e14cf9201b77d94526dc982dc09c)

Comment: `UPDATE filenames
  SET filename = REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '_[^.]*', '')
WHERE filename REGEXP '.*\.jpg$';` would be perfect but unfortunately I use MAMP and it's stuck with MySQL 5.7 so I can't use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and there doesn't appear to be a replacement.

Comment: That worked perfectly with my 5.7 MySQL. One thing I have just noticed after running this on a few hundred values is that .jpg that didn't have an underscore also got changed. It's a problem I can fix a replace of `.jpg.jpg` with just `.jpg` but I wondered if there is a way to ignore .jpg without the underscores?

Comment: @SilkSpin Sorry, I had not thought of that. I've updated the solution. I think you can fix those that were already updated with `UPDATE filenames SET filename = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(filename, '.jpg', 1),'.jpg') WHERE filename REGEXP '.*\.jpg\.jpg$';` See the last bits on [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e0ccd74f0c04c025c7df92cf832ae28f). A simple `REPLACE(filename, '.jpg.jpg', '.jpg')` will work too of course. I hope you're testing on a copy table :)

Comment: That's brilliant @Scratte. I would've had to run multiple smaller queries to get those results and your way is now just one step. I'm working with Magento so I'm always doing db backups ;o) I've destroyed quite a few trying databases trying to get around this issue of Magento incrementing image filenames. It stems from the need to reuse certain images. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will help you:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg', '_', 1),'.', SUBSTRING_INDEX('image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg','.',-1)) AS ConcatenatedString
union all
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('this_can_also_be_a_value', '_', 1),'.jpg') AS ConcatenatedString
```

Query result:

```
image-name-3.jpg
this.jpg
```

Comment: I can see how that query would find the values but I need to run an update or replace on the `value` column in a specific table. How would I do that?

Comment: you can put in update statement like update table_name set column_name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg', '_', 1),'.', SUBSTRING_INDEX('image-name-3_1_1_1.jpg','.',-1))  where condition

Comment: you have to make assumption for the image type if no extension in the string.